# synchornize several videos so they start at the same time

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have a html page in which I have

```
<div class="video">
<video control="controls" src="some_video.mp4"></video>
<p>Play:
<span class="state"> Paused</span>
<input class="together" type="button" value="All">
</p>
</div>
```

several times for several videos.

Then in a javascript attached to the page I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var running = false
$("div.video input.together").each(function() {
        $(this).on("click", function() {
            running = !running
            $("video").each(function() {
                if(running)  {
                    $(this).get(0).play();
                }
                else{
                    $(this).get(0).pause();
                }
            })
            $("div.video span.state").each(function() {
                if(running){
                    $(this).text("Running");
                }
                else{
                    $(this).text("Paused");
                }
            })
        })
    })


}
```

Now, this makes a button in which when I click all videos play or stop together.

The problem is that when I put this html on a NAS and I click it, sometimes some videos takes some time to load while the other start , defeating the purpose of playing them together. (when the videos are loaded, it works ok)

How can I modify the code so that the videos start when all of them are loaded?

NOTE: The number of videos is not set (This page is made by Python Dominate and depending on the data it can have any number of videos)

Comment: Have a look at [MDN's reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#events). It lists all events any MediaElement can trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check to wait until each video has fired a 'canplaythrough' event.

This means the video element thinks it can play the full video without having to stop for buffering etc.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaythrough_event

In practice, you may find that in some cases the video element is not always correct (e.g. some unpredictable network interruption our slowdown could still cause buffering) but in general it 'should' work.